# Twitter bootstrap fixed layout issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have gotten a weird problem with my columns using Twitter bootstrap. Setting up a test page that should behave like the example here: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/hero.html . Here's the html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">        
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/24d7eb4f/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/24d7eb4f/css/bootstrap-yii.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/24d7eb4f/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/8b15478e/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/24d7eb4f/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span4" style="border: 1px solid red;"></div>
            <div class="span4" style="border: 1px solid red;"></div>
            <div class="span4" style="border: 1px solid red;"></div>
        </div>            
    </div>
</body>
```

Should produce the result shown in the link above, but i get the third `span4` on the next line, it gets pushed under the two first. Apart from this the container behaves as expected, i.e. it is centered.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Note: I am using Twitter bootstrap as an add on to Yii here. Should not be the problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Border adds pixels to width so `span4` is now increased to 302px (border-left: 1px + border-right: 1px) from 300px and hence comes to the next line. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/BUaEj/1/)

`border: 1px solid red;`

You can give a background instead of border to test.

Check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/BUaEj/)

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the feedback @anpsmn . You are correct of course that you get some extra padding with borders. The thing that threw me of here is that I am using this inside nav and tab, which causes the same effect as this bordering. Am i right about this?

Comment: Yes, border adds pixels and will make the element come to next line if there is not enough space.

Answer (score 0):

Applying a `border` is breaking your layout by adding some width to your `span`s.

The native bootstrap solution for handling "column styles" are the `.well` elements.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="well well-with-my-style">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.well-with-my-style {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: none;
    /* whatever... */
}
```

That way, you will respect the native layout and take profit from the `.well` element, but remember that you'll have to override `.well` styles with your own (using `.well-with-my-style` class).

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the feedback @simbirsk . You are correct of course that you get some extra padding with borders. The thing that threw me of here is that I am using this inside nav and tab, which causes the same effect as this bordering. Am i right about this?

Comment: Tabs (left or right, I supose) do not cause any problem whenever the layout inside each tab is fluid. It's a different issue, I think.